# what's different in lua require path with "/" or "."

Tags: lua, require

I see some lua code using require path in two way.
eg:

```
require("a/b/c")
or
require("a.b.c")
```

so i want to know what's different above.
And can we use this two kinds way in programa same time?

Comment: I don't think it matters.  More of a convenience thing, so you don't have to deal with forward slashes, and backslashes.

Comment: The argument to a `require` call is a module name and not a path to a module file without a file extension. This is why the first one is broken and the second one is ok. This becomes obvious for C-based modules where the module name is used not only to find the shared library (where slashes would probably work) but also to derive the name of the symbol to load from that library (where slashes most definitely will not work). If you need slashes, put them in `package.path` (or `package.cpath`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is to do that in the Lua console `lua -i` - So...

```
>lua -i
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require("a/b/c")
stdin:1: module 'a/b/c' not found:
    no field package.preload['a/b/c']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/a/b/c.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/a/b/c/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/a/b/c.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/a/b/c/init.lua'
    no file './a/b/c.lua'
    no file './a/b/c/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/a/b/c.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
    no file './a/b/c.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
> require("a.b.c")
stdin:1: module 'a.b.c' not found:
    no field package.preload['a.b.c']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/a/b/c.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/a/b/c/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/a/b/c.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/a/b/c/init.lua'
    no file './a/b/c.lua'
    no file './a/b/c/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/a/b/c.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
    no file './a/b/c.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/a.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
    no file './a.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
>
```

Note this appeared in the output with `a.b.c` but not `a/b/c`:

```
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/a.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
    no file './a.so'
```

...does this answer your question?

> Try this...

```
>lua -i
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> dump=function(dump) for key,value in pairs(dump) do io.write(string.format("%s = %s\n",key,value)) end
>> end
> dump(package.preload)
> package.preload["a.b.c"]=function() return "WHATSUP" end
> dump(package.loaded)
package = table: 0x56614f00
io = table: 0x56615860
math = table: 0x56616ce0
os = table: 0x56615f40
coroutine = table: 0x566153a0
bit32 = table: 0x56618730
debug = table: 0x56618350
utf8 = table: 0x56617880
string = table: 0x566166b0
_G = table: 0x566136d0
table = table: 0x56615640
> require("a.b.c")
WHATSUP
> dump(package.loaded)
package = table: 0x56614f00
io = table: 0x56615860
math = table: 0x56616ce0
os = table: 0x56615f40
coroutine = table: 0x566153a0
a.b.c = WHATSUP
bit32 = table: 0x56618730
debug = table: 0x56618350
utf8 = table: 0x56617880
string = table: 0x566166b0
_G = table: 0x566136d0
table = table: 0x56615640
> ;-)
```

Comment: `no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'` appears in both.

Comment: Yes, like ```init.lua``` that been loaded if they exists. Like autoexec.bat and config.sys on old [dos]

Comment: no i mean it is in your list of `Note this appeared in the output with a.b.c but not a/b/c:` but it appears in both, technical it appears twice in `'a.b.c'` so I can understand if you keep it in the list

Comment: The Note is not from me - It is a edit from @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica - Maybe overseen?

Comment: I included it since it appears an extra time, and is part of a block that only occurs with `a.b.c`. If you think it makes more sense to just include the other two lines, feel free to change it to that.

Comment: For me it is ok.  My intention was to show the errors from require and how to fix the first ```no field``` error. In fact require looks first in package.loaded. So a ```package.loaded.foo='bar'``` can be loaded with: ```foo=require('foo')``` without to set an special ```package.preload``` 'field' function that returns the value to package.loaded. Of course it make more sense for files to load them with loadfile() to the desired package.loaded since loadfile() support paths directly without extending package.path.

Comment: Another answer i found for my rethoric question: Why these kind of execution for ```result=load('return math.pi*2')()``` and ```result=loadfile('/path/to/luacode')()``` was the ```package.preload()``` functionality - When you write a preload function and use loadfile() for that the extra ```()``` are not needed because preload is doing this. Short example with load() ```do package.preload.koys=load('return "WHATSUP"') koys=require('koys') print(koys) end``` - So, i think, load() and loadfile() are designed for use in ```package.preload()```